# If shemittah passed, is it still honorable to repay a debt?

Tags: money, shmita, borrowing

If Reuven owes Shimon $10, and shemittah passed, and Reuven remembered he never paid Shimon, yet he still wants to, should he? Is it honorable?

Answer (score 13):

[Mishnah Shevi'it 10:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sheviit.10.9?lang=bi):

> הַמַּחֲזִיר חוֹב בַּשְּׁבִיעִית, רוּחַ חֲכָמִים נוֹחָה מִמֶּנּוּ.
>
> One who repays his debts after the seventh year, the sages are pleased with him.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly OK, [as Joel K already answered](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/117071/501), and actually the lender may even *peer pressure* him to do so.

**However**, the money needs to be given as a gift, and not as repayment of the loan, otherwise, the lender may not accept the money.

See the [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 180:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.180.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) who spells out the details.

> לֹוֶה שֶׁבָּא לִפְרֹעַ לַמַּלְוֶה חוֹב שֶׁעָבַר עָלָיו שְׁמִטָּה, יֹאמַר לוֹ הַמַּלְוֶה, מְשַׁמֵּט אֲנִי אֶת הַחוֹב וּכְבָר נִפְטַרְתָּ מִמֶּנִי.‏
> אִם אָמַר לוֹ הַלֹּוֶה, אַף עַל פִּי כֵן רוֹצֶה אֲנִי שֶׁתְּקַבֵּל מִמֶּנִּי, מֻתָּר לַמַּלְוֶה לְקַבְּלוֹ מִמֶּנוּ.‏
> וְאַל יֹאמַר הַלּוֶֹה, בְּחוֹבִי אֲנִי נוֹתֵן לְךָ, אֶלָּא יֹאמַר לוֹ, שֶׁלִּי הֵם וּבְמַתָּנָה אֲנִי נוֹתְנָם לָךְ.‏
> וְיָכוֹל הַמַּלְוֶה לַעֲשוֹת הִשְׁתַּדְּלוּת וְהִתְפָּעֲלוּת, שֶׁיֹּאמַר הַלֹּוֶה שֶׁהוּא נוֹתְנָם לוֹ בְּמַתָּנָה. וְאִם אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לִפְעֹל זֹאת, אַל יִקָּחֵם.‏

> If a borrower comes to pay his debt to the lender after the Shemitah had passed, the lender should say to him: "I have canceled your debt, and you are released from my claims." 
> If the borrower says: "Even so, I want you to accept the money," the lender is permitted to accept it. 
> However, the borrower should not say, "I am paying this on the account of my debt;" rather, he should say to him: "The money is mine, and I am giving it to you as a gift." 
> The lender is [even] permitted to make an effort to persuade the borrower to say "I am giving you the money as a gift." However, if he is unable to [persuade him] he may not accept the money from him.

Comment: Can you source your claim that "the lender may even peer pressure him to" repay the loan?

Comment: @msh219 I guess it's the last paragraph of the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch

Comment: @robev: That paragraph doesn't say that the lender can pressure the borrower to repay the debt, only that the lender can pressure the borrower to agree that it's a gift (because the lender can't accept it otherwise).